# Placing moving objects next to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in ios development and I am having difficulty looping a group of 13 objects so that they will be placed next to each other with an exact gap of 46 while moving. With my current code, the objects are looping but there is a randomized gap between them each time they move on and off the screen.

```
-(void)Move{
    Spike1.center = CGPointMake(Spike1.center.x - 1, Spike1.center.y);
    Spike2.center = CGPointMake(Spike2.center.x - 1, Spike2.center.y);
    Spike3.center = CGPointMake(Spike3.center.x - 1, Spike3.center.y);
    Spike4.center = CGPointMake(Spike4.center.x - 1, Spike4.center.y);
    Spike5.center = CGPointMake(Spike5.center.x - 1, Spike5.center.y);
    Spike6.center = CGPointMake(Spike6.center.x - 1, Spike6.center.y);
    Spike7.center = CGPointMake(Spike7.center.x - 1, Spike7.center.y);
    Spike8.center = CGPointMake(Spike8.center.x - 1, Spike8.center.y);
    Spike9.center = CGPointMake(Spike9.center.x - 1, Spike9.center.y);
    Spike10.center = CGPointMake(Spike10.center.x - 1, Spike10.center.y);
    Spike11.center = CGPointMake(Spike11.center.x - 1, Spike11.center.y);
    Spike12.center = CGPointMake(Spike12.center.x - 1, Spike12.center.y);
    Spike13.center = CGPointMake(Spike13.center.x - 1, Spike13.center.y);

    if (Spike1.center.x < 0) {
        Spike1.center = CGPointMake(594, Spike1.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike2.center.x < 0) {
        Spike2.center = CGPointMake(640, Spike2.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike3.center.x < 0) {
        Spike3.center = CGPointMake(686, Spike3.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike4.center.x < 0) {
        Spike4.center = CGPointMake(732, Spike4.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike5.center.x < 0) {
        Spike5.center = CGPointMake(778, Spike5.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike6.center.x < 0) {
        Spike6.center = CGPointMake(824, Spike6.center.y);
    }

    if (Spike7.center.x < 0) {
        Spike7.center = CGPointMake(870, Spike7.center.y);
    }
```

^ this is my current code. for this. are there any suggestions to how I can correct this issue?

Comment: What are these objects?  Also you need to store these "objects" in an array and loop over them; manipulating 13 variables in a similar way is tedious and error prone, and we must avoid tedium at all cost ;-)

Comment: I'm agreed with @trojanfoe Also, surely UIView animations would simplify this even more? But perhaps you're not animating the move and are simply moving their locations once.